# Use of Multithreading In web apps

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multithreading

I am using an Application server for calling Oracle Reports and I have a URL to call the report. When the report is called the server converts it into PDF but when report contains large data it takes a lot of time to load. I want to do in asp.net that when I call the report url it opens the PDF file and copies it into the root of my web folder. The next time when I call the URL it opens the PDF file and creates a new PDF on backend for next call.

I have made this function to download file

```
Sub DownloadFile_Sap()
        Dim remoteuri As String = "http://appsrv01.shakarganj.com.pk:7778/reports/rwservlet?reptest&report=sap_dashboard"
        Dim filename As String = Server.MapPath("~/Files/rwservlet_reptest&report=sap_dashboard.pdf")
        Dim mywebClient As New Net.WebClient()
        mywebClient.DownloadFile(remoteuri, filename)
    End Sub
```

and I called it on linkbutton -  code is below

```
Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LinkButton1.Click
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "openfile", "window.open('http://202.125.144.34:83/Files/rwservlet_reptest&report=sap_dashboard.pdf');", True)
        DownloadFile_Sap()

    End Sub
```

But when I call this method on link button it gets same time as it got on download file. What can I do  so that the Link button calls the file from the  folder in a second and downloads the file on the backend?

Link button code is here

```
 <asp:linkbutton ID="Linkbutton1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Files/rwservlet_reptest&report=sap_dashboard.pdf" OnClick="DownloadFile_Sap"  >LinkButton</asp:linkbutton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Multithreading` in asp.net web application is not a good idea.

You have limited source on `IIS thread pool` and if you try to use this in a such operation,
you will have serious problems on production.

So what you can do it, split to `Windows service`. Do all expensive operations on windows service application. Make the communication between your web app and windows service app through `sql table`.

EDIT:

Here the path for this:

You will have to visual studio projects
1- your web app(you have alrady it)
2- new project that will run as windows service.

Then you will have sql table containing:
Report_Name, Ready_Flag

From web app you fill Report_Name
From windows service report is prepared and set Ready_Flag to true
You can query from web app Ready_Flag if set true, once it is true,
you serve to client

Comment: Sir can u please tell me any bit example so that i code have idea to do next

Comment: I have understood the database flag method but what will windows service do

Comment: I want to complete a process on backend not on front of user

Answer (score 0):

You can not decrease the download time even if you pre create PDF and keep it in the directory. So Download time i think can not be reduced but the PDF as you said can be reduced by creating it ahead of the request and placing it in the directory.

Comment: I meant that i want to call the file from directory on one trigger and at the same time on backend download the file please tell me any event or method to do this that the download time should be used on backend not reduced